# Type error for Query string with postgresql-simple

Tags: haskell, overloaded-strings

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51013242/figuring-out-the-source-of-a-database-error-using-haskell-postgresql-simple), I have a query template that I've constructed using the [`interpolate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolate-0.2.0/docs/Data-String-Interpolate.html) package, which I'm then trying to pass to the `query_`/`execute_` functions from [`postgresql-simple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.4.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html).  But the compiler refuses, with the the error

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Query’
      Expected type: Query
      Actual type: String
```

The notable passage from the doc pages for postgresql-simple is, "To most easily construct a query, enable GHC's `OverloadedStrings` language extension and write your query as a normal literal string."  So, it would appear that the following should work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad (void)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.String.Interpolate (i)

-- schema_name.table_name
type Table = String

dropTableIfExistsQuery :: Table -> String
dropTableIfExistsQuery tbl = [i| DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #{tbl} |]

dropTableIfExists :: Connection -> Table -> IO ()
dropTableIfExists conn tbl = void $ execute_ conn $ dropTableIfExistsQuery tbl
```

But this won't compile, as above:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Query’
  Expected type: Query
    Actual type: String
• In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘dropTableIfExistsQuery tbl’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘execute_ conn $ dropTableIfExistsQuery tbl’
  In the expression:
    void $ execute_ conn $ dropTableIfExistsQuery tbl
```

What gives?  Why isn't `OverloadedStrings` working here?

Comment: Your code specifically says `dropTableeIfExistsQuery :: ... -> String`, so it returns a string. No overloading is involved.

Comment: @melpomene The `execute_`/`query_` families of functions have a signature like `Connection -> Query -> IO Int64`, where `Query` is a type that has an instance of `IsString`.  My understanding is that I can pass a `String` as a `Query` and the `OverloadedStrings` extension will take care of the coercion.  But that appears to not be the case, in spite of what the documentation says.  My question is, why?

Comment: `OverloadedStrings` changes the type of string literals (i.e. `"double-quoted stuff like this"`) from `String` to `IsString a => a`. That's all.

Comment: You are also subject to a SQL injection attack if you don't have control over the value of `tbl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OverloadedStrings` only affects string literals, not all terms of type `String`. If you have a `String` which is not a literal, you may explicitly convert it to any instance of `IsString` (e.g. `Query`) using:

```
fromString :: IsString a => String -> a
```

N.B. I don't know enough about `Query` and the other libraries you're using to say whether `fromString` has the behavior you need; I claim only that it has the type you need.